# What is the purpose of the PowerProfile class in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was tasked with writing an app that gets details of how much power is being consumed by different apps. I was looking at the PowerProfile class and I am not sure what exactly it is used for. There is this method in the class

```
Returns the average current in mA consumed by the subsystem
Parameters:
type the subsystem type
Returns:
the average current in milliAmps.
public double getAveragePower(String type) {
    if (sPowerMap.containsKey(type)) {
        Object data = sPowerMap.get(type);
        if (data instanceof Double[]) {
            return ((Double[])data)[0];
        } else {
            return (Double) sPowerMap.get(type);
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If I test it by using it as follows:

```
String POWER_BLUETOOTH_ACTIVE = "bluetooth.active";
String POWER_PROFILE = "com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile";
try{
    Constructor[] constructors = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE).getConstructors();
    Constructor c = constructors[0];
    Class[] paramTypes = c.getParameterTypes();
    Object params = (Object) this.getActivity().getBaseContext();
    Object filledObject = c.newInstance(params);
    Method batteryMeth1 = Class.forName(POWER_PROFILE).getMethod("getAveragePower", String.class);
    Object barglist1[] = new Object[1];
    barglist1[0] = new Object[1];
    barglist1[0] = POWER_BLUETOOTH_ACTIVE;
    double btlife = (Double) btMeth1.invoke(filledObject, barglist1);
    Log.d("BatteryLog", "average BT active mAH " + btlife);
    btInfo.setText("avg bt mAH is " + btlife);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d("BTLOg", "average BT active mAH " + btlife);
}
```

Then I always get 38.8 for bluetooth mAH used, even if I use my Bluetooth a bunch in between runs. Is this normal, and why would I always get the same mAH values?

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth is consuming power when pairing with other device or transmitting/receiving mode. Pairing mode is responsible to discover active bluetooth nearby then make a connection for the first time to get the MAC address & name of the bluetooth. It's like you are going to say hi to a beautiful stranger (pairing), it takes much courage ,no? then you can make a conversation (transmitting/receiving mode). Power consume in pairing mode is greater (more courage) than bluetooth transmittin/receiving mode whether there are data streamed or not. But for some bluetooth module embedded in your device there are some bluetooth supported sleep mode. The power draw in sleep mode is so little.

So in your case, maybe the bluetooth already in paired mode so it's consume the same amount. Try to pair the bluetooth or discovery [bluetooth in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) it might consume more power

Comment: For my bluetooth activities I was actually using an app I wrote which calls sdptool browse, sdptool records, and sdptool search (and I used every single UUID for search) with the tree flag enabled for each one so I was going about as robust as you can get with discovery. I also paired at one point too. I guess the real question I`m getting at is, are those mAH values static or dynamic? They seemed static to me but I only tried with Bluetooth.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Are you trying to get different power consumption for each profile(SPP, A2DP,etc)?

Comment: That would be nice but no, that`s not my goal -- I`m really trying to get the different power consumption for the different activities in the power profile class (radio scanning, wifi scanning, bluetooth activity, wi-fi active, etc).

Comment: Well, I've been only play with a bluetooth module HC-05 anyway i can't have the answer for your question. But, according to datasheet the module consume 25mA when pairing and 8mA when socket connected, whether there's data transmitted/received or not. So i guess it works the same way with the bluetooth in your Android. What kind of device you try to connect to by the way? Android or remote device? Have you tried performin a single test for each discovery, pairing, and transmiting with your program?

Comment: I was using the HTC One-X phone and my remote device was another android phone (LG L86C). The application I was using just did the three service discovery steps as I mentioned above and then made a hands-free connection to query for CHLD and BRSF values. I did three tests -- one where I called this method without doing any bluetooth activity, one where I called this method after running the app once, and one where I called this method after running the app multiple times and all reported 38.8 mAH although now that I think about it I wasn`t running both apps concurrently. I will try with that.